# Resettable RangeBase (Slider) in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I've implemented a custom Slider that derives from RangeBase that has an added ResetValue property that can be used to reset the Value to the initial value. Unfortunately this requires double binding the value source and also use the OneTime binding mode for ResetValue.

```
<ButtonSlider
        Minimum="0" Maximum="500" TickFrequency="1"
        Value="{Binding Path=MaxVoltageUv}"
        ResetValue="{Binding Path=MaxVoltageUv, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Ideally it would have a boolean dependency property CanReset that would capture the ResetValue on first bind if it were enabled. I've tried implementing it by capturing the first time Value is set, but for some reason this only works some of the time.

It first overrides the metadata on the ValueProperty:

```
        ValueProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ButtonSlider), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnValueChanged, OnCoerceValue));
```

And then implements custom coerce and value changed handlers.

```
    private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var buttonSlider = ((ButtonSlider)d);
        if (buttonSlider != null)
        {
            if (!buttonSlider.valueInitialized && e.NewValue is double)
            {
                buttonSlider.resetValue = (double)e.NewValue;
                buttonSlider.valueInitialized = true;
            }

            buttonSlider.CheckResetEnabled();
        }
    }

    private static object OnCoerceValue(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var buttonSlider = ((ButtonSlider)d);
        if (buttonSlider != null)
        {
            if(baseValue is double)
                return Math.Max(Math.Min((double)baseValue, buttonSlider.Maximum), buttonSlider.Minimum);
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
```

For some reason the OnValueChanged is called with a Value of 0 while the initial bind should have been 2. This seems to be related to data templating. Controls that are not on a data template work correctly.

Is there any other way to capture an initial value of a dependency property?

Comment: Could you provide few more details about the situation when `OnValueChanged` is being called with `e.NewValue` being 0? What's the value of `e.OldValue` at that point? Is the binding set on the property at that particular moment, and if it is, what's the binding source value? And what's the property's default value?

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts

- Verify that `MaxVoltageUv` which you bind to is a double.
- Remove the dependency property `ResetValue` it is just creating noise in trying to resolve this.
- `0` could be the default value of the dependency property which gets set *before* the actual binding. Why not put in a `-1.0` as the default along with the logic in the `OnValueChanged` to detect that scenario and ignore until a proper value comes through.

Comment: The problem then is that an initial value/reset value of 0 would not work, because it is not descernable from the 0 value that comes through when using datatemplating.

Comment: @Wouter That is why later I specified that the control could set its initial value at -1 and if the control sees that value it goes to zero for the actual display.

Answer (score 0):

If both the data context and the binding are set in XAML, you can use the Loaded event of your custom control to store the current value as the reset value. This will also work if your control is in a data template for instance.

If the data context is set from code, this will only work if it is set before the control has been added to the logical tree.